# Backspace not working in kali linux terminal hosted on backbox using virtual box

Tags: kali-linux

I need to fix the issue of non-working of backspace in kali terminal as tried plenty of things like

```
chsh -s /bin/bash
```

and

```
sudo chsh -s /bin/bash yourusername
```

Comment: may be related to ncurses version

Answer (score 0):

The choice of shell has little to do with this.  Ditto ncurses. You may have read this: [Backspace, Tab, Del and arrow keys not working in terminal (using ssh)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/163802/backspace-tab-del-and-arrow-keys-not-working-in-terminal-using-ssh).  I could pick it apart, but see no useful information on that page.

Your terminal emulator typically sends either ASCII *backspace* (code 7, control G) or ASCII *delete* (code 127, shown as `^?` but actually no standard key assignment).  In the shell, your **`stty`** settings show this configured as the **`erase`** value, e.g.,

```
$ stty -a
speed 38400 baud; rows 40; columns 80; line = 0;
intr = ^C; quit = ^\; erase = ^H; kill = ^U; eof = ^D; eol = <undef>;
eol2 = <undef>; swtch = <undef>; start = ^Q; stop = ^S; susp = ^Z; rprnt = ^R;
werase = ^W; lnext = ^V; flush = ^O; min = 1; time = 0;
-parenb -parodd cs8 -hupcl -cstopb cread -clocal -crtscts
-ignbrk -brkint -ignpar -parmrk -inpck -istrip -inlcr -igncr icrnl ixon -ixoff
-iuclc -ixany -imaxbel -iutf8
opost -olcuc -ocrnl onlcr -onocr -onlret -ofill -ofdel nl0 cr0 tab0 bs0 vt0 ff0
isig icanon iexten echo echoe echok -echonl -noflsh -xcase -tostop -echoprt
echoctl echoke
```

Usually this is done automatically; some configurations hard-code the choice.  If your system doesn't do this, you can add an `stty` command to your shell initialization, e.g.,

```
stty erase ^H
stty erase ^?
```

according to your preference.

Further reading:

- [The Linux keyboard and console HOWTO: 5. Delete and Backspace](http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/Keyboard-and-Console-HOWTO-5.html)
- [Why doesn't my delete key work?](http://invisible-island.net/xterm/xterm.faq.html#xterm_erase)